# Перебор структуры в golang | invalid operation: cannot index progs (variable of type interface{})

Tags: golang

У меня есть такая структура

```
type StructurePrograms struct {
        ID          int64
        ProductName string
        Avatar      string
}
```

Получаю записи из БД и кладу их в progs при помощи append (получается 2 записи)

```
func SQLmyPrograms(email string) (interface{}) {
....
    progs := []StructurePrograms{}
    for res.Next(){
        
            p := StructurePrograms{}
            err := res.Scan(&p.ID, &p.ProductName, &p.Avatar)
            if err != nil{
                fmt.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            
            progs = append(progs, p)
        }
        
        return progs
```

Если  до return я попробую вывести на экран нулевой элемент все будет ок.

```
fmt.Println(progs[0])
```

Вызываю данную функцию

```
 progs := SQLmyPrograms(email)
fmt.Println(progs[0])
```

Пробую вывести в консоль, во время компиляции получаю ошибку

```
invalid operation: cannot index progs (variable of type interface{})
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Если вывести в консоль значения переменных они одинаковые что до return что после.

```
[{1 test /img/test.png}{2 test2 /img/test.png}]
```

Если вывести тип переменной то и там и там тип: `main.StructurePrograms`

Comment: Приведите к типу, если не ошибаюсь вот так: ```progs.([]StructurePrograms)```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло! Я пробовал progs.(StructurePrograms) но не работало, сейчас понял свою ошибку

Comment: мой вам совет - не используйте пустые интерфейсы

Comment: Почему, и как лучше сделать?